# React Native app throws "No bundle URL present" but works on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

When I run my React Native app with `react-native run-ios`, about half the time it gives me the "No bundle URL present" error

[image]

and in the console it's hanging on "Loading dependency graph, done"

[image]

If I reload it always works fine, so it's not really a problem, I just want to understand why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common reason can be internet proxy. If you have set any SOCKS proxy please unchecked that.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons for this. The cache remains in the build portion and can cause errors, most of which occur in the `HTTP` address acceptance section. It is recommended to look at the `NSAppTransportSecurity` section or `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` section in the `info.list` file.

If you don't find a problem here, you might encounter a problem at the `build` part. In this case, you can delete the `build` file and run

```
rm -rf ios/build
```

Answer (score -1):

"No bundle URL present" means your iOS project doesn't have main.jsbundle file. 
main.jsbundle file is used to manage the resources (like image and custom font) in release mode.
After reloading, working fine is some curioused but may be there will be some issue in App Store release or release testing like image doesn't show correctly...
It is just my opinion.
Thank